# How to add a top border to Xamarin Forms App Shell Tabbar

Tags: .net, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Using the Xamarin Forms App Shell template, it’s obvious how to change the background colour of the Tabbar, but I can’t see a way to add a top border, or even a drop shadow, as is common in many tab bar styles.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe it’s more standard practice to add a bottom border to each tab page?

Comment: Looking at XF source code on github, I'd say this isn't naturally supported by all the platforms, so it isn't an option in XF. Unfortunately, Shell has a complicated implementation; the `ShellRenderer`s on the different platforms are different. I don't see any easy way to modify the renderers, nor to "cheat" ("overlay" some adornments on top of the Shell page). May not be possible to use Shell, and have this degree of control over appearance.

Answer (score 2):

**Android:**

You could use the  `CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker` to change something for the bottomview.

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(ShellCustomRenderer))]
namespace ShellDemo.Droid
{
class ShellCustomRenderer : ShellRenderer
{

    public ShellCustomRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
    {
        return new CustomBottomNavAppearance();
    }
}

public class CustomBottomNavAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
    {

    }

    public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
    {
        //put your code here
       
    }
}
}
```

- Shadow: Create a Shadow.xml in Drawable of Android.

  ```
  <shape 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient
   android:startColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
   android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
   android:angle="90" />
  </shape>
  ```

  And then set the shadow as background of bottomview in SetAppearance.

  ```
  bottomView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.shadow);
  ```
- Border line of the bottomview. Create a Border_top.xml in Drawable of Android.

  ```
   <layer-list 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:top="5dip">
     <shape>
       <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"> 
       </solid>
    </shape>
   </item>
   </layer-list>
  ```

  And then set it as background.

  ```
  bottomView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.border_top);
  ```

**iOS:**

You could use the  `CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker` to change the tabbar.

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(ShellCustomRenderer))]
namespace ShellDemo.iOS
{
public class ShellCustomRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
    {
        return new TabBarAppearance();
    }

}

public class TabBarAppearance : IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
{
    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void ResetAppearance(UITabBarController controller)
    {
        
    }

    public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
    }

    public void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Shadow: The iOS has a default shadow there.

Comment: That’s certainly a place where changes can be made, but you haven’t included making an actual border change and I can’t see how to do that either.

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it.